# Morse code text converter to audio using Android studio 2.3

Tags: android, audio

so I want to make application that can convert text to Morse code (text - text, text - audio, text - lights). Text to text converter is already done, next is to convert Morse code from text to audio. The problem is, when I want to play 2 audio, ( one for dot, and another one for dash ) they always play at the same time because I put `if` statement for my code. So, what I have to do with my code so the application can play dot sound after dash sound or dash sound after dot sound ?

- my opinion is I put all the Morse code (text) to `queue` and then take it one by one to compare dot and dash.

  ```
  public void morseSound(View view) {
          String value = sentences;

          final MediaPlayer dot = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep1);
          final MediaPlayer dash = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep2);

          Button playSound = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnMorse2);

  //        List<Character> mString = new ArrayList<>();
  //        for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length(); i++) {
  //            mString.add(value.charAt(i));
  //       }
  //        TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
  //        test.setText(mString.toString());

          playSound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  for (int i = 0; i < sentences.length(); i++) {
                      if (sentences.charAt(i) == '-') {
                          dash.start();
                      } else dot.start();
                  }
              }
          });

      }
  ```

Comment: did you mistakenly tag this javascript?

Comment: ohh, i'm sorry.

Comment: obviously you should use `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener` and "play next char" there ... also it would be good to add some "silent/mute" between (naive way it would be make use of `Handler.postDelayed`)

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks ! @Selvin